# iOS - Parse: findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock with completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm fetching data using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` but I have to use the data when all of it is gathered. I don't know how to implement a callback or anything which would alert me once all the data is retrieved and ready for me to use. Is there any way to get alerted?

Code:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray* array, NSError* error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        if([array count] > 0)
        {
            PFObject* relationship = [array objectAtIndex:0];

            if([relationship.objectId length] > 0)
            {
                if([[relationship objectForKey:@"initiatedBy"] isEqualToString:parseID]) // relationship initiated by current user -youLike
                {
                    [youLike addObject:relationship];
                    NSLog(@"youLike added");
                }
                else
                {
                    [likeYou addObject:relationship];
                    NSLog(@"likeYou added");
                }
            }
            else NSLog(@"Custom error when cycling through user relationships: objectId is nil");
            }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Custom error when cycling through user relationships: Relationship at index %d could not be found in database", i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error when cycling through user relationships: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`Blocks`**

Declare the `Block` (Here you **choose** your `block types`)

```
typedef void (^YourBlock)(NSArray *array, NSError *error);
```

Add the `block` and the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` in a method.

```
- (void) yourMethod:(YourBlock)block {
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        //Do your things here if you want change something.
        //For instance: convert types, convert errors.
        block(array, error); //Is called when every thing is retrieve.
    }
}
```

**Call** your method in the Application

```
SomeClass *someClass = [SomeClass alloc]init];
[[object getScoresFromParse:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
    //Everything complete here.
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use blocks.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{


    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray* array, NSError* error)
    {
        if(!error)
        {

            if([array count] > 0)
            {
                PFObject* relationship = [array objectAtIndex:0];

                if([relationship.objectId length] > 0)
                {

                    // It will be called when Parse finishes.
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        if([[relationship objectForKey:@"initiatedBy"] isEqualToString:parseID]) // relationship initiated by current user -youLike
                        {
                            [youLike addObject:relationship];
                            NSLog(@"youLike added");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            [likeYou addObject:relationship];
                            NSLog(@"likeYou added");
                        }

                        // [...yourcode...]

                    });

                }
                else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSLog(@"Custom error when cycling through user relationships: objectId is nil");
                    });
                }

            }

        }

    }];


}];
```